# Interpreting regular expressions using find in Linux confusion

Tags: linux, find

I am attempting to use the `find` command and came across an article at http://www.linux.ie/newusers/beginners-linux-guide/find.php which states:

> The wildcard character is escaped with a slash so BASH sends a literal asterisk to the find utility as an argument instead of performing filename expansion and passing any number of files in as arguments.

for the command `find . -name up\*`.

Being new to the world of Linux I don't quite understand how the use of a backslash which is meant to escape the meta character `*` is interpreted and returns results as though as it is being passed to `find`. Does it mean if I use the `-name` option I have to use a backslash to pass a wildcard and if I don't use `-name` I don't have to use a backslash? Also is the backslash being used so that the bash shell doesn't attempt to expand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that you are using the term "regular expression" rather loosely.. What you are dealing with in the `find` `-name` option is rather close in behaviour to a `shell`  `glob`... On the other hand, the `find` `-regex` option  uses a regular-expression search. You can choose which style of regex to use via the -regextyp option.. The choice of currently-implemented types is: emacs (this is the default), posix-awk, posix-basic, posix-egrep and posix-extended. ...

How you deal with the backslash and asterisk, etc. can vary depending on what you want to do.   If you want `find -name` to consider it an asterisk as a wildcard character, then you need to ensure that it is **NOT** escaped when `find` actually reads the pattern from the command line.

To ensure that  *find* gets it in an unescaped form, you must prevent the *shell* (typically *bash*) from performing it's *(very powerful) shell expansion on your asterisk... To **protect** it you **MUST** *escape it* at the command-line level (ie. "escape it" in the eyes of the shell)..  The key concept at this point is *"protect"*...

You can protect your asterisk from the shell in three ways:

- use `'`single quotes`'`
- use `"`double quotes`"`
- use a `\` backslash (and *no* quotes)

So, for `find` to see your asterisk as a wildcard, any of the following "protection" methods will work.

- `find -name up'*'`
- `find -name up"*"`
- `find -name up\*`
- `find -name 'up*'`
- `find -name "up*"`
- `find -name "up"\*`

Note that the shell will *never* perform expansion on anything in `'`single quotes`'` ... `"`double quotes`"` are a different story..

Comment: One of the best answers. Forgive my n00bness but am confused by the statement `then you need to ensure that it is NOT escaped when find actually reads the pattern from the command line.` and the followed by `To protect it you MUST escape it at the command-line level`. Further confounded by `Note that the shell will never perform expansion on anything in 'single quotes' ... "double quotes" are a different story.`. So looking at the first statement you mention it must not be escaped

Comment: but followed by that you mention escaping it at a command-line level which I assume means within the command itself e.g. `find . -name up\*`. This is further compounded by the last statement where you mention no expansion is made on anything with single quotes. Do you mean that the bash shell does not expand anything with single quotes but the `find` command does?

Comment: Yes, 'in single quotes' refers to the `shell`, ie. the command-line. A called app (like 'find') is free to process your asterisk (internally) as it sees fit. Getting it into `find` as a simple asterisk, which is what you need in this situation, is the type of thing you always need to be alert to. The bash shell can do some amazing pre-processig of things on the command-line, but **you** need to manage it..  Quotes and backslash are the control mechanisms.  `find  -name up\*` and `'up*'` protect the asterisk from the shell. If it wasn't protected, it would expand to (many) matching filenames.

Comment: ... Once inside `find`'s domain, the asterisk is a literal asterisk again (ie, it is NOT escaped)...   The bash command-line "protection" methods (quotes/backslash) are discarded by bash; they are only there as indicators to bash as to how to handle its  command-line expansions **...** There are 6 categories of shell expansion: **1**. brace expansion   
**2**. tilde expansion
**3**. parameter expansion
**4**. variable expansion
**5**. word splitting
**6**. pathname expansion

Comment: So assuming I did not escape the meta characters e.g. `*` does this mean that the command `find . -name up*` would be interpreted by both the bash shell as well as `find`? Secondly when you say discarded, what do you mean exactly? Lastly would you mind elaborating on the 6 categories of shell expansion?

Comment: `find` is not related to the `shell` in any way, other than that the *shell* is the user **interface** which allows you to run such a program. A unix style *shell* has *added* features which affect the command-line. When you run `find`, you not only need to consider what parameters `find` needs, but you also need to consider **how** to present those parameters to `bash`. ie. There are two layers to consider. Escaping something, per se, has no magic to it. The issue is: *For a given situation, do I **need** to protect/ something, so that it won't be subject to special shell pre-processing?*

Comment: When the shell's pre-processing is done with, and `find` has received its parameters (*internally*), `find` too may need to have some characters *escaped*.. For example, make 2 files. One has an asterisk in its name; `touch foo'*'foo foo-bar` .. now let's try 2 variants of a `find` command.  **1**. `find -maxdepth 1 -name foo\*` or `'foo*'` will find *both* files..  **2**. `find -maxdepth 1 -name foo\\*\*` or `'foo\**'` will find *only* `foo*foo` .. For more info: `man bash` (or, for more detail `info bash`), otherwise try [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), or just google the terms

Answer (score 2):

What you're missing here is that both the shell and find expand *.  You want find to expand it, so you need to hide it from the shell.

You're looking for all the files off the current directory whose names begin with "on", right?  If you let the shell expand the *, you won't get that. Suppose your current directory contains the files "upwards" and "uplift". Then the shell changes your command to

```
find . -name upward uplift
```

which is bad syntax for find. If there are no matching files, then the shell leaves the argument alone — but it's good to get into the habit of using commands that work right regardless of details like that.